# Cannot copy Rule Tile in Project Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Unity Version 2020.3.30f1 Personal** In Unity I have a Rule Tile that auto tiles my 2d platforms for me. There is a duplicate tile-set that the player toggles between which does not have the rule tile set up. But since it will have the same rules I just want to copy and paste the rule tile in the Unity editor to manually replace the Sprites. I prefer this to creating a new Rule Tile and setting up all the rules again. But I cannot find a way to copy a rule tile like you would in the scene manager (Right click copy and ctr V). Is there no option to copy items in the project manager?
Am I required to copy files in the file browser (I am hesitant to do this since it generates a meta file and the Rule Tile is still early access)?
EDIT: This ended up being the answer, exported files through file browser to update the unity asset files that were previously populating the rule tiles.

[image: Unity View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting my tile palette files and renaming them over my old files (in my unity asset folder) updated the tile sheet and rule tiles.